# JavaScript массив, помогите с решением

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Требуется реализовать функцию `task(x)`, возвращающую массив из числа `x`, переданного ей в качестве аргумента, и ещё 9 подряд идущих за `x` чисел.

т.е. `[x, x + 1, ..., x + 9]`. Затрудняюсь с реализацией.

Comment: `const task = x => new Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => x + i)`?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Либо так, `const task = x => Array.from({ length: 10 }, (e, i) => x + i);`

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и ясный вариант с циклом:

```js
function task(x) {
  const array = [];
  for (const max = x + 9; x <= max; x++) {
    array.push(x);
  }
  return array
}

console.log(task(0));
```

Из более коротких и сложных вариантов, кроме тех, что вам предложили:

```js
const task = x => [...function* (max) { while (x <= max) yield x++; }(x + 9)];

console.log(task(0));
```